# Hide Zero values in a line chart Kendo ui

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Is there anyway to hide data points with zero (0) value in a line chart?  I'm currently using the line chart(Kendo) and can't seem to find an easy way to do this.  Basically a line shows up at the 0 value on the graph and I rather not show the line at all.The data binding one of the line end value is zero(i have to remove it).Sample data like [30,50,40,75,0]

Here i'm providing the html code

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                url: "dataVizWebService.asmx/GetSellInOfficeTrends",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#chart").kendoChart({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: data.d,
                            value: "#={0}>0"
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: "bottom"
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: "Population"
                        },
                        series: [
                                    {
                                        type: "line",
                                        field: "Population2010",
                                        name: "Population2010",
                                        axis: "Year",
                                        color: "#4a7ebb"
                                    }, {
                                        type: "line",
                                        field: "Population2011",
                                        name: "Population2011",
                                        axis: "Year",
                                        color: "#be4b48"
                                    }, {
                                        type: "line",
                                        field: "Population2012",
                                        name: "Population2012",
                                        axis: "Year",
                                        color: "#98b954"
                                    }, {
                                        type: "line",
                                        field: "Population2013",
                                        name: "Population2013",
                                        axis: "Year",
                                        dashType: "dash",
                                        color: "#000000"
                                    }
                                    ],
                        valueAxis: [{
                            name: "Year",
                            title: { text: "Population in Millions" }
                        }],
                        categoryAxis: {
                            field: "Week",
                            majorTickType: "none",
                            labels: {
                                skip: 0
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            visible: true
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing values property in Kendoui API Documentation. You can use those properties and check what ever useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up to [parse()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemaparse-function) of the dataSource and there you can change the data which will be passed to the chart. Example:

```
function parse(items) {
  var item,
      result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    if (item.value !== 0) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

$(function() {
  var data = [{ value: 30 },{ value: 50 },{ value: 40 },{ value: 75 }, { value: 0 }];
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
      data: data,
      schema: {
        parse: parse
      } 
    },
    series: [{
      type: "line",
      field: "value"
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,here i'm having four line series and the data is coming from database with five column's(1st is WeekName,2nd Population2010,Population2011,Population2012,Population2013) in the population2013 column data i'm having the value zero.that value line(zero pointing) having i want to hide/remove it.

Comment: Is it possible to return the values as null? This would be more semantic and will allow you to use the http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#seriestype--line-missingvalues-stringdefault option

Comment: Sorry for late response.I have tried the link given but the chart with the line with zeros is showing.